# Какие HTML элементы не рендерят содержание как HTML?

Tags: html

Например, внутри `<textarea>` можно поместить теги, и они не будут рендериться как `html`:

```
<textarea cols="80" rows="5">
<b>this is a bold</b> <i>text</i>   
</textarea>
```

Какие ещё элементы обладают таким свойством? Интересует в порядке общего развития.

Конкретная задача, решать которую **не надо** в рамках этого вопроса — хочу держать большой кусок `html` наготове, чтобы потом вытащить его в переменную `JS`, и, пропарсив как темплейт, вставить где-то на странице.

Comment: Вот и держите в JS

Comment: @sergiks, валидатор будет ругаться на тэги внутри textarea.

Comment: @stck на что именно?
@istem перечитайте вопрос.

Comment: @sergiks, на то что у вас `<b>this is a bold</b> <i>text</i> `, хотя внутри должно содержаться `&lt;b&gt;this is a bold&lt;/b&gt; &lt;i&gt;text&lt;/i&gt; `

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Собственно зачем делать костыли, когда можно просто добавлять контент в скрытый див?

```
<style id='test'>
    <PRE>
        {if $CONT}{$CONT}{/if}

        {$GAL*100/30+$CONT}
    </PRE>
</style>

<script id='test2'>
    /*<PRE>
        {if $CONT}{$CONT}{/if}

        {$GAL*100/30+$CONT}
    </PRE>*/
</script>

<script>
    alert(document.getElementById('test').innerHTML);
    alert(document.getElementById('test2').innerHTML.replace(/(\/\*)|(\*\/)/g, ''));
</script>
```

Comment: продублируются id некоторых элементов. Про html теги есть, что сказать?

Comment: Так понапихайте в разные элементы: p, div, span, header, footer, etc. Вариант со style и javascript в своём ответе привел. А вообще, так ответ istem'a самый правильный.

Comment: вариант с закомменченным кодом внутри `<script>` красив.