# Как добавить HTML-код в контейнер

Tags: javascript, html

Привет.
Нужно добавить код

```
 <div class="tr">
      <div class="name">
        <input type="text" value="найменование"  />
      </div>
      <div class="cont">
         <input type="text" value="к-тво"  />
      </div>
      <div class="price">
         <input type="text" value="цена"  />
      </div>
      <input type="button" value="удалить" class="adds"  onclick="obj.add_str()"/>
   </div>
```

в элемент, причем я потом хочу еще добавить обработчики событий на поля и кнопку динамически.
Как лучше добавить этот огромный кусок кода в другой блок `<div>`?
Создавать каждый элемент `createElement` и добавлять через  `appendChild` это будет очень долго.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Пожалуйста смотрите на дату, ведь вопрос был задан три года назад (задан 13 ноя '12 в 14:04).

Comment: Да, к сожалению, люди часто не помечают вопросы, как отмеченные... и наш Дух Сообщестсва их достает из пыли...

Answer (score 1):

Можно поизвращаться и засунуть блоки в контейнеры, что описаны в данном топике: [Какие HTML элементы не рендерят содержание как HTML?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/159152/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-html-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-html) Потом прочитать содержимое этих блоков (innerHTML) и запилить в нужное место. А чо, довольно годно.